# FCM REST API web push sending rate limits (global)

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

There is no exact info about sending web push notifications via REST API:

- https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send (legacy HTTP)
- https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/.../messages:send (HTTP V1)

I'm interested in the real rate limit **to FCM platform**, not to 1 subscriber or 1 device

[Throttling and scaling doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#throttling-and-scaling) does not cover all the details specifically about the global REST API rate limiting, but at the same time, the documentation describes [errors that exceed the quota](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/ErrorCode) and [timeouts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) - again without details.

Answer (score 0):

The REST API and the Admin FCM APIs allow you to multicast a message to a list of device registration tokens. You can specify up to 500 device registration tokens per invocation. Is it what you want?

Link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-multiple-devices

Comment: I know about batching, but I'm interested in the requests rate with which I can send my requests to FCM